# Search condition in where clause postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres, can anyone help me understand the role of `?`  in the where clause?

```
Select * from tablename1 as a 
join tablename2 as e
on a.column1 = ? and a.id = e.id 
and e.range between ? and ?;
```

Comment: Looks like parameter placeholders.

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-example - look at the second example.

Answer (score 0):

These look like place holders for parameters that you need to assign in code outside of a SQL editor.  The statement probably gets compiled by Postgres and you could call it many times with different sets of parameters.

Comment: Thanks Faizan that helps for sure.

Answer (score 0):

? just represents that you should place appropriate id in a.colum1=? and two values after between clause if you want to get date in some range.

Comment: Thanks Faizan that helps for sure.